# Why condition if don't working and "skip"?

Tags: c#

I try writing console app, which print shortest word from the text and if we have several short words, they must also be print. But app print only one word, even I writing 2 identical word. The condition for checking the same words in length does not work for some reason. I know that this can be implemented somehow conveniently, but I did from what I knew.

```
static string MinMax(string[] words)
        {
            string[] minValue = new string[] { Convert.ToString(words[0]) };
            int count = 0;
            string minWords = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (minValue.Length > words[i].Length)
                {
                    minValue[0] = words[i]; 
                    for (int e = 0; e < words.Length; e++)
                    {
                        if (minValue[0].Length == words[e].Length) // Проверяет другие слова с такой же длиной и должен добавлять их
                        {
                            minValue[count++] = words[e];
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(minValue[e]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < minValue.Length; i++)
            {
                minWords = minValue[i].ToString();
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(minWords + " = minwords") ;
            Console.ReadKey();
            return minWords;
        }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] words = text.Split(' ', ',', '.', '!', '?', ':', ';', '-', '"', ';');
        string min = MinMax(words);
        Console.WriteLine(min);
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: why not just `string shortest = words.OrderBy(x=>x.Length).Last()`?

Comment: `minWords` will always be 1 word because it's a `string`, not a `string[]`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why it's not possible to at least output the minValue[e] array with several numbers

Comment: This doesn't make any sense; `if (minValue.Length > words[i].Length)` in other words, you're asking if the array `minValue` have more elements than the length of this string....

Answer (score 0):

You have algorighmic problems in your code.

LINQ solution:

```
string? text = Console.ReadLine();
string[] words = text?.Split(' ', ',', '.', '!', '?', ':', ';', '-', '"', ';') ?? new string[0];

//take the shortest length
int shortestLength = words.Min(x => x.Length);
//take the shortest words by length
var shortestWords = words.Where(x => x.Length == shortestLength);

foreach(var word in shortestWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Your solution should be like this:

```
static List<string> MinMax(string[] words)
{
    var shortestWords = new List<string>();
    int shortestLength = int.MaxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        if (shortestLength > words[i].Length)
            shortestLength = words[i].Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].Length == shortestLength)
            shortestWords.Add(words[i]);
    }
    return shortestWords;
}
```

And get all words with minimum length:

```
foreach (var word in MinMax(words))
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```